# turn off autoplay for audio file

Tags: html, audio

I included an audio greeting in a website I'm making, and want audio to only start when a user click play. I set it up so that `autoplay="false`, and `autostart="false"`

here is my code so far

```
<section>           
    <h1>Welcome to Morlans Famous Shop!</h1>
    <object>
        <param name="greetings" value="audio/EN_sta60_black_market_00083397_M.wav" />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="false"/>
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
        <embed src="audio/EN_sta60_black_market_00083397_M.wav" controller="true" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/wav"  pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
    </object>
    <p>Hello there. Welcome to Morlans famous shop. You want many good supplies, yes? </p>
    <p>My shop carries all sorts of supplies need to survive the tough environments that the galaxy has to offer. From medigel, to armor, Morlans famous shop carries it all.</p>
    <p>Oh, you will be pleased I think. Very good things I have, you will see.</p>
</section>
```

is there anything that I am missing?, any help would be appreciated

Comment: why don't you use one `<audio>` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)? [html5 resources](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/resources)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(soundfile) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""
    +soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"
    loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
```

Have a look at that. Taken from this site.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm

That requires javascript though.

Still having some issues? Look here to get an understanding of the use of audio http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp